# How do I take a build in test flight and promote it to be available on the App Store

Tags: ios, mobile, app-store, testflight, visual-studio-app-center

I am using app-center to push an app to test flight. Do I have to use app-center to distribute to the App Store or is there a way inside test-flight to push a build to the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a software to upload to testflight, you'd most likely be using the same software to upload it to the public app store.